# Django TypeError: str returned non-string (type NoneType) in admin change view

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm encountering an error when trying to access the admin change view for an order object in my Django application. The error message states: "TypeError: str returned non-string (type NoneType)." This issue occurs when accessing the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/accounts/order/38/change/.

Here are some additional details about the problem:

Django version: 4.2
Python version: 3.11.3
Exception location: C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py, line 1504
The error seems to be related to the **str** method defined in one of my models. Here's the relevant code snippet:

`class Order(models.Model): # ... def __str__(self): if self.product: return str(self.product) return f"No Product (Order #{self.id})"`

I suspect that there might be an issue with the product field in the Order model, causing the **str** method to return None. This error is then propagated to the admin change view, resulting in the mentioned error.

I'm unsure how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to fix this error and ensure that the **str** method returns a string value as expected.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
class Product(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Residential', 'Residential'),
        ('Commercial', 'Commercial'),
        ('Auto', 'Auto'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name if self.name is not None else ''
```

Here is my Orders model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Processing', 'Processing'),
        ('Ready to be picked-up', 'Ready to be picked-up'),
        ('Order Rejected', 'Order Rejected'),
    )
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)
    #note = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        if self.product:
            return str(self.product)
        return f"No Product (Order #{self.id})"


> Traceback:
> 
> 
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/accounts/order/38/change/
> 
> Django Version: 4.2 Python Version: 3.11.3
> 
>     Installed Applications:
>     ['django.contrib.admin',
>      'django.contrib.auth',
>      'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>      'django.contrib.sessions',
>      'django.contrib.messages',
>      'django.contrib.staticfiles',
>      'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
>      'django_filters']
>     Installed Middleware:
>     ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
>      'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>      'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>      'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>      'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>      'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
>      'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
> 
> 
> Template error: In template C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\includes\fieldset.html, error at line 20
>   
> 
>      __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
>        10 :                 <div>
>        11 :                     {% if not line.fields|length == 1 and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
>        12 :                         <div class="flex-container{% if not line.fields|length == 1 %} fieldBox{% if field.field.name %}
> field-{{ field.field.name }}{% endif %}{% if not field.is_readonly and
> field.errors %} errors{% endif %}{% if field.field.is_hidden %}
> hidden{% endif %}{% elif field.is_checkbox %} checkbox-row{% endif
> %}">
>        13 :                             {% if field.is_checkbox %}
>        14 :                                 {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
>        15 :                             {% else %}
>        16 :                                 {{ field.label_tag }}
>        17 :                                 {% if field.is_readonly %}
>        18 :                                     <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
>        19 :                                 {% else %}
>        20 :                                      {{ field.field }} 
>        21 :                                 {% endif %}
>        22 :                             {% endif %}
>        23 :                         </div>
>        24 :                     {% if field.field.help_text %}
>        25 :                         <div class="help"{% if field.field.id_for_label %} id="{{ field.field.id_for_label
> }}_helptext"{% endif %}>
>        26 :                             <div>{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</div>
>        27 :                         </div>
>        28 :                     {% endif %}
>        29 :                 </div>
>        30 :             {% endfor %}
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py",
> line 55, in inner
> 
> response = get_response(request)
>                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
> line 220, in _get_response
> 
> response = response.render()
>                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py",
> line 111, in render
> 
> self.content = self.rendered_content
>                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py",
> line 89, in rendered_content
> 
> return template.render(context, self._request)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py",
> line 61, in render
>    
> 
>      return self.template.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 175, in render
> 
> return self._render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 167, in _render
> 
> return self.nodelist.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1005, in render
> 
> return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in
> self]))
>                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1005, in <listcomp>
> 
> return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in
> self]))
>                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 966, in render_annotated
> 
> return self.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py",
> line 157, in render
> 
> return compiled_parent._render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 167, in _render
> 
> return self.nodelist.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1005, in render
> 
> return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in
> self]))
>                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1005, in <listcomp>
> 
> return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in
> self]))
>                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 966, in render_annotated
> 
> return self.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py",
> line 157, in render
> 
> return compiled_parent._render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 167, in _render
>    
> 
>      return self.nodelist.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1005, in render
> 
> return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in
> self]))
>                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1005, in <listcomp>
> 
> return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in
> self]))
>                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 966, in render_annotated
> 
> return self.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py",
> line 63, in render
> 
>     result = block.nodelist.render(context)
>              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1005, in render
>     return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
>                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1005, in <listcomp>
>     return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
>                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 966, in render_annotated
>     return self.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py",
> line 63, in render
>     result = block.nodelist.render(context)
>              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1005, in render
>     return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
>                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1005, in <listcomp>
>     return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
>                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 966, in render_annotated
>     return self.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py",
> line 238, in render
>     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
>                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 966, in render_annotated
>     return self.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py",
> line 208, in render
>     return template.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 177, in render
>     return self._render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 167, in _render
>     return self.nodelist.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1005, in render
>     return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
>                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1005, in <listcomp>
>     return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
>                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 966, in render_annotated
>     return self.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py",
> line 238, in render
>     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
>                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 966, in render_annotated
>     return self.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py",
> line 238, in render
>     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
>                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 966, in render_annotated
>     return self.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py",
> line 321, in render
>     return nodelist.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1005, in render
>     return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
>                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1005, in <listcomp>
>     return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
>                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 966, in render_annotated
>     return self.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py",
> line 321, in render
>     return nodelist.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1005, in render
>     return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
>                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File
> "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1005, in <listcomp>
>     return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
>                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 966, in render_annotated
>     return self.render(context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1070, in render
>     return render_value_in_context(output, context)
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py",
> line 1047, in render_value_in_context
>     value = str(value)
>             ^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py",
> line 420, in <lambda>
>     klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))
>                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py",
> line 34, in __str__
>     return self.as_widget()
>            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\boundfield.py",
> line 107, in as_widget
>     return widget.render(
>               File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py",
> line 280, in render
>     context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)
>               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\widgets.py",
> line 312, in get_context
>     "rendered_widget": self.widget.render(name, value, attrs),
>                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py",
> line 280, in render
>     context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)
>               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py",
> line 734, in get_context
>     context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
>               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn
> Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py",
> line 693, in get_context
>     context["widget"]["optgroups"] = self.optgroups(
>                                         File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py",
> line 633, in optgroups
>     for index, (option_value, option_label) in enumerate(self.choices):
>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py",
> line 1404, in __iter__
>     yield self.choice(obj)
>           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py",
> line 1418, in choice
>     self.field.label_from_instance(obj),
>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\Brenn Alexander\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py",
> line 1504, in label_from_instance
>     return str(obj)
>            ^^^^^^^^
> 
> Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/accounts/order/38/change/
> Exception Value: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

Comment: Can you share your `Order` model? Sometimes this error comes from the relationships rather than the model itself.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this. Can you share a sample repro project on GitHub?